# Odoo inheritance and (lack of) polymorphism

Tags: inheritance, odoo, openerp-8

I would like to construct an object (**objA**), which over the course of its existence takes on many different types of *status* (**objB**). However, each different type of status is its own beast which varies depending on its *type* (**type1**, **type2**, **type3**, ...).

Apparently Odoo / OpenERP does not support polymorphism so the introduction of the intermediary status **objB** is intended to cloak the different types of status with hopes that **objA** may have a One2Many field consisting of its ''status history''.

Now, I am stuck with the notions of inheritance that Odoo documentation describes as *Traditional* vs *Delegation* and am unsure which is which. Furthermore, if this type of manipulation is possible, will it be possible that all attributes can be realized in **objA**'s form-view?

My only guess is something like as follows;

```
class ObjA(models.Model):
    _name = 'obja'
    generic_attribute = fields.Char(string="Generic Attribute", default="Anything")
    status_history = fields.One2many('obja.status', 'obja.id', string="History")

class Status(models.Model):
    _name = 'obja.status'
    generic_status_attribute = fields.Date(string="Status start")
    _inherits = ['status.type1', 'status.type2', 'status.type3']

class Type1(models.Model):
    _name = 'status.type1'

class Type2(models.Model):
    _name = 'status.type3'

class Type3(models.Model):
    _name = 'status.type3'
```

Comment: I think there possibly is an example in odoo itself, which is implementing your requirement. `ir.ui.menu` can take different types (models) of ir.actions, which are inheriting `ir.actions.actions`. You can find the classes in base/ir.